# Chrome on macOS fullscreen shortcut unexpectedly changed

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, fullscreen

I know for sure I didn't change it but somehow my Chrome browser's shortcut to enter or exit fullscreen mode has been changed to this combo (instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image]

I've looked and found some answers but I don't want to set a custom keyboard shortcut like the answers suggested. I've restarted my Mac, reinstalled Chrome but the problem persists.

It seems like there was an operation or app at some point changed the shortcut without my knowledge.

macOS 12.1
Chrome Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (arm64)

Answer (score 9):

After some investigation, I found it's a recent behavior change in macOS Monterey, not Chrome. All Apple apps changed the previous <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. And Apple updated their document, take [Books](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/guide/books/ibk0a716cf4-9a70-485b-9835-72e3c7ed6c29/4.1/mac/12.0) for example.
[image]

I workaround it by adding custom shortcuts to "All Applications".
[image]

Comment: Why, apple, why do you change shortcuts everyone is already used to and familiar with. I use non-apple external keyboard that has no FN key (that was actually also the reason i bought it). Is this some way to promote your $150+ external keyboards? I know I can change the shortcut back. But it will not probably work in all apps - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141323

Comment: Wow! I was debugging my own chrome extension. Saved the day!
The question is Why the f*..?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this. It seems the latest update of Google Chrome to Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (x86_64) changed the full screen shortcut. In my case, it changed from "Ctrl + Cmd + F" to "fn + F". However, I reverted this change by adding a custom shortcut to my macOS "System Preferences" in the "Keyboard" section.[image: System Preferences -> Keyboard -> App Shortcuts -> Google Chrome.app -> Enter Full Screen & Ctrl + Cmd + F, Exit Full Screen & Ctrl + Cmd + F]

Comment: Yeah. I did this too. Just wondered if there's a way to reset it instead of setting custom shortcuts.